# Fail to create fat partition on USB pen

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, live-usb

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92rub.png)

Hello everyone. I'm pretty ignorant on computer matters and I have a problem. I used a USB stick as bootable device to install anti-x on a old computer. The problem is that I cannot recover the usb stick to its normal function. My windows pc does not even recognize it, my linux laptop does but I can't format it to FAT partition. When I try to using the default app on ubuntu, it just says:

**Error creating partition on /dev/sdb: Failed to read partition table on device '/dev/sdb' (invalid partition table - recursive partition on /dev/sdb.) (udisk-error-quark,0)**

I don't know how to recover the usb pen. If any of you could help me I'd be really glad. Thanks in advance.

P.s. please be patient and guide me step by step. As I said,unfortunately I'm ignorant on the subject and I struggle to use the terminal. Also, English is not my first language.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Comment: You need to delete all partitions and only then create a new one. Or you can use the MKUSB (developed by the previous commentator) with its recover to use a mass storage device feature.

Comment: Thank you guys, MKUSB worked perfectly!